# unwanted double cookie installing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

My cookie code:

```
$(function() {
 $("#background").on('submit', function(e) {
    var src = $(this).find("input").val();
    $.cookie("background", src, {expires: 4*7});
 });
 $(".clear").click( function() {
    $.cookie("background",'');
    $("body").css("background-image", 'url('+$.cookie("background")+')');
 });
 $("body").css("background-image", 'url('+$.cookie("background")+')');
});
```

I use this on my (en)homepage and on the /nl.
The cookie works fine, but when I install the cookie on the (en)homepage it will set the cookie and when I go to the /nl page it will not use the already installed cookie but you need to set another one again, so it will not use the cookie of the homepage but it will use it own one.

html code:

```
<form id="background">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
<button class="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: So you mean, you have two different subdomains, and you want a cookie set on one of them to be available on the other as well? Then you have to specify the base domain while setting the cookie. (And btw., cookies are not “installed”, they are simply _set_.)

Comment: No, www.domain.com and www.domain.com/nl/

Comment: Well then specify the correct path for where you cookie should be valid while setting it.

Comment: from what it sounds like, make sure path is being set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way can be:

```
//check if cookie already exists
if($.cookie('background')) {
//Clear the already existing cookie, here you can use 
$.removeCookie(‘background’) 
}
```

and then create a new cookie which will work when you switch between 2 different URLs.

Comment: That's good...if the above suggestions helped you get on track to achieve the solution, please mark/vote it as the answer with tweaks you made. Basic idea remains the same, you have to blend in with your implementation to make it work.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I was totally forgotten to mark the answer as the worked answer